# Is it possible to Humanize TimeSpan to years with Humanizer?

Tags: humanizer

We want to leverage the [Humanizer package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekHumanizerMakesNETDataTypesMoreHuman.aspx) (as we use it elsewhere) and don't want to add more similar libraries or hand rolled code.

I have timespans some of which are thousands of days. I want to humanize them and convert them to years. Now I appreciate a year varies but if I am converting 10000 days to years - I am happy with the loss of precision.

```
 TimeSpan.FromDays(10000).Humanize(minUnit: TimeUnit.Year);
```

returns

> "no time"

TimeSpan.FromDays(10000).Humanize();

returns

> "1428 weeks"

If I convert them to DateTimes by adding to now.

```
DateTime.Today.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(10000)).Humanize();
```

returns

> "27 years from now"

It always appends from now - can I remove the from now part in an inbuilt way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out Humanizer cannot describe `TimeSpan`s with a accuracy larger than weeks. This is because it is impossible to know if a year has 365 or 366 days or how many days a month is.

However, this is possible when it needs to describe the relative `TimeSpan` (i.e some time ago) because Humanizer is then able to calculate if the day has 365 or 366 days.

Once [Pull request #604](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/pull/604) has been merged this functionality should be available and calculate a year as 365.25 days. This will results in a loss of precision, but as you've mention this is not an issue.